# how can I make a USB stick bootable in EFI

Tags: macos, fedora, bios, usb-flash-drive

I have a MacBook and I would like to check out Fedora. I have created a bootable USB stick with UNetbootin, but it won't boot on my mac. It does on a friends PC (win7). I think this has to do with BIOS vs. EFI, bit how can I solve the problem so I can boot from it on my mac.

Comment: anyone? I can do stuff trought terminal if that's whats needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) has great guide on how to do this in OS X.

Answer (score 12):

The previous answer just includes a link to [Ubuntu's instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos), so I'll summarize the steps. I've used these steps to create Ubuntu installation media for a Dell server configured for EFI boot.

- Launch Disk Utility
- Select View -> Show All Devices
- Right-click or select the target device, and choose "Erase".
- Choose MS-DOS (FAT), GUID Partition Map
- Click "Erase"

Once complete, download and run [Etcher](https://etcher.io/). Select your ISO and click "Flash".

Comment: Very simple, thanks so much for this! Worked for me (oct. 2019) with a old MacBooc Air.