# Make a DOS Boot Disk on a USB stick using a Mac

Tags: macos, boot, ms-dos, freedos, unetbootin

I'm trying to make a DOS Boot Disk on a USB stick using a Mac.
I don't really care if it's MS-DOS or FreeDOS, as long as I can use it to flash a faulty BIOS on a X9DRL-iF from SuperMicro.

I don't want to boot a Mac, and I don't want Linux.

To see first if the boot stick works I'm trying to boot an old test PC made of a Gigabyte card and a Core 2 Duo proc.

I've tried different combinations of Unetbootin, dd of the Freedos FullUSB IMG, nothing worked.
I'm always stuck on that screen (pic included).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I make a USB stick bootable in EFI](https://superuser.com/questions/369874/how-can-i-make-a-usb-stick-bootable-in-efi)

Comment: Sorry not at all, I don't want to boot a Mac, and I don't want Linux. Thanks anyway

Comment: That's not what [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1284730/8672) is about. Read it.

Comment: You meant using Etcher instead of Unetbootin or dd? I did and I still can't boot, get the same screen. I'm flashing FD13FULL.img. Thank you.

Comment: Your problem might be that you're creating an EFI boot, which DOS doesn't support.

Comment: No, /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.5 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_16 FD13-FULL               536.7 MB   disk2s1

Comment: I'm just flashing FD13FULL.img on a MBR/FAT usb drive. I've tried dd, Unetbootin, and now Etcher.

Comment: The bootstrap should be in the image, then written when flashed,making the FAT partition bootable, or am I wrong?

Comment: No, the boot sector needs to be added. Usually "bootable" is a parameter of the flashing program.

Comment: Or did I understannd your comment the other way around, as in I am trying to boot with the BIOS set to UEFI? I'm confused.

Comment: Anyway there is no such option in Etcher.

Comment: Try Rufus. See also this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1688959/clarification-on-using-rufus-to-create-a-bootable-live-freedos-usb-drive).

Comment: I do not have Windows

Comment: So it is, my bad.

Comment: "I do not have Windows:" Use a VM, if it makes it easier. Recently I wanted to run a 32-bit Windows program to have it create a bootable *32-bit OS* USB drive. After spending hours trying numerous ways, I used Oracle's *VirtualBox*, which took about 1/2 hour to set up, run the 32=bit app, and make the USB drive. Any VM should work. Disadvantage: VM  saved to disk take up 40 GB, if you care to keep it.

Comment: Pippik, I seen that route and found it an overkill. What seemed like a trivial question ended up being a black hole. I've done hundreds of MacOS or UX/Linux boot devices and never struggled like with this DOS thing. Also I am totally MS-DOS/Windows illiterate, hence my question here. Thanks

Comment: Involved but necessary is not overkill. That is the correct way to accomplish this, especially considering the things you've already tried. DrMoishe has provided a likely solution; I suggest you try it rather than dismissing it.